# Problem in finding the maximum value of $\tan^2(\theta-\phi)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $\tan\theta$ = $n\tan\phi$,then what is the maximum value of $\tan^2(\theta-\phi)$?

My attempt:

First I tried to reach $\tan^2(\theta-\phi)$ using the given condition, but couldn't.

Next, I used the property that $AM\geq GM$ to reach:

$$\dfrac{\sin^4(\theta-\phi)+\sec^4(\theta-\phi)}2  \geq \tan^2(\theta-\phi)$$

Now, I am unable to continue from here  by simplifying it. Can someone suggest some methods to proceed from here or provide a hint to solve this problem differently?

PS: The answer is $\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\{\theta,\phi\}\subset\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $n>0$ then by AM-GM we obtain:

$$\tan^2(\theta-\phi)=\left(\frac{\tan\theta-\tan\phi}{1+\tan\theta\tan\phi}\right)^2=\left(\frac{(n-1)\tan\phi}{1+n\tan^2\phi}\right)^2=$$
$$=\frac{(n-1)^2}{(\cot\phi+n\tan\phi)^2}\leq\frac{(n-1)^2}{(2\sqrt{\cot\phi\cdot n\tan\phi})^2}=\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}.$$
The equality occurs for $\cot\phi=n\tan\phi$, which says that $\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}$ is the answer.

Otherwise, the maximum does not exist, of course, because we can get $\cot\phi+n\tan\phi\rightarrow0$.

Comment: @Abcd I fixed my post. See now please.

Comment: @Abcd I just divided the nominator and the denominator by $\tan\phi$ and in the denominator we obtain: $\frac{1}{\tan\phi}+n\tan\phi=\cot\phi+n\tan\phi$.

Comment: @Abcd It's AM-GM: for positives $a$ and $b$ we have $a+b\geq2\sqrt{ab}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L(\theta,\phi,\lambda)$ be the Lagrangian of your optimisation problem:
$$L(\theta,\phi\,\lambda) = \tan^2{(\theta-\phi)}-\lambda[\tan{(\theta)}-n\tan{(\phi)}]\tag{*}$$
The extrema of the Lagrangian are found with:
$$\vec{grad}\,L(\theta,\phi\,\lambda)=\vec{0}\tag{**}$$
Being the last equation of $(**)$ the constraint $\tan{(\theta)}=n\tan{(\phi)}$.

You can see that if $\lambda=0$ one reaches a minimum when $\theta=\phi$, and when it is not, the solution for $\phi$ and $\theta$ is given by the following equations:
$$\tan^2{(\theta)}=\frac{1}{n}\qquad \tan^2{(\phi)}=n  \tag{***}$$

Therefore the value of the function using $(**)$is:
$$\tan^2{(\theta-\phi)}=\left(\frac{\tan{(\theta)}-\tan{(\phi)}}{1+\tan{(\theta)}\tan{(\phi)}}\right)^2= \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}\right)^2=\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}$$

Comment: How can a pre-calculus student understand your solution? It's complicated for me :(

Comment: It is true, that it is advance calculus. I did not read your tags below the question, sorry. On the other hand this method is really powerful and simple. It is based on surfaces and their gradients (concepts that are calculus basics). Hope you learn it soon! @Abcd